# Activities created by API not emailing assignee

Tags: api, activities

Creating an activity with either API (api3, api4) does not trigger an email to the assignee. Is this by design or is there a problem with my instance of CiviCRM? Activities generated via the GUI and via webform do send emails to assignees. The checkbox to "Notify Activity Assignees" in Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences is checked.

CiviCRM 5.61.4, Drupal 7.97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is necessarily by design, but adding activities via API doesn't send emails to assignees. Seems like it should if you have the option checked.

You could [post an issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues/) and even potentially fix this yourself, if you're able.

Comment: Created https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/45078/5446

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right, API calls do not send email notifications. Like Lars, I'm not sure whether that's intentional or not - but either way you'll have to do that yourself once you've created the activity. [Here's some code](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/blob/94f82288cd611dd62a6bafee60c96d9bb5510d56/includes/acf/acfe/form-actions/cwps-acf-acfe-form-action-activity.php#L1285-L1316) you can adapt to your needs - the basic gist is that there are two CiviCRM settings that have a bearing on whether the email gets sent, followed by the send procedure itself.

Comment: CRM_Activity_BAO_Activity::sendToAssignee(), thanks!